# Cannot use jquery event on woff?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, woff

I'm building a website using `bootstrap` and `fontawesome`. And now I want to use JQuery `onclick` event on an `icon-plus` icon. But nothing happened after I click the icon.
I found some bootstrap examples who can work right and saw that browser download icon as `png`. But `fontawesome` provides icon as `woff`. 
My jquery code as follow:

```
$(".icon-plus").on("click",function(e){
  $("#form").append(...);
});
```

Comment: What exactly did you want to have happen to the icon onclick. If you are using a woff font icon and you want to change the color of it on click, add a class to it onclick and define a color for the class in your CSS. If you want the icon to change to another icon, you will need to replace the character used to produce the icon when the onclick event occurs.

Comment: doesn't matter what font to use... image or text would not matter either... can you show some codes?